# $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f_n =f.$ Prove that $f′_n =f′$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am studying for a real analysis qualifying exam.  Was hoping that there was a very slick proof for this?  Thanks.

Let $f_1, f_2, . . . , f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ be non-decreasing right-continuous functions such that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty
f_n =f.$ Prove that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty$ $f′_n =f′$ a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $f_n(x)=\mu_n([0,x])$ for some nonnegative measure $\mu_n$. Write that as $d\mu_n=f'_n\,d\lambda+d\nu_n$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure and $\nu_n$ is singular. Do the same for $f$: $d\mu=f'\,d\lambda+d\nu$. Let $N$ be a (Borel) null set where $\nu_n([0,1]\setminus N)=0$ for all $n$, and likewise $\nu([0,1]\setminus N)=0$.

By assumption $\sum_n\mu_n([0,x])=\mu([0,x])$ for all $x$, and it follows that $\sum_n\mu_n(E)=\mu(E)$ for all Borel sets $E$. When $E\cap N=\emptyset$ then (using the montone convergence theorem in the first part)
$$ \int_E\sum_nf_n'\,d\lambda=\sum_n\int_E f_n'\,d\lambda=\sum_n\mu_n(E)=\mu(E)=\int_E f'\,d\lambda,$$
and we're done.

Comment: I think you wanted the null set to have $\nu_n([0,1] - N) = 0$, not $\mu_n([0,1] - N) = 0$. That is, $N$ is the support of the measures $\nu, \nu_1, \nu_2, \dots$, which is of Lebesgue measure zero by the singular property.

Comment: @Ian You're right. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Is there a way to do this without the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem?

Comment: @Nina I can’t think of a way, off the top of my head.